# Remove left/right padding from 2 equal bootstrap columns to align them equally with upper div

Tags: css

I have two equal bootstrap columns which are below another full-size column like below:

[image: test]

I want to match the left of the first column to the left of the upper DIV, and match the right of the second column to the right of the upper DIV, like below:

[image]

But if I remove the left and right padding from columns, it creates problem when they are stacked on small-screen. The second column appears far from left compared to right, like below:

[image]

```
.section-1 {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.section-2 {
  padding-right: 0px;
}
```

I can't figure out the ideal way to align them properly as I want (leftmost/rightmost) with the upper div, and still get correct result when stacked.

[Here is the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/rishabh1990/qwkcmuL6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is write a media query for the smaller screen sizes. 
Something along the lines of

```
@media(max-width:599px)
{
  .section-1 {
  padding: 0px;
}

.section-2 {
  padding: 0px;
}
}
```

Here is a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qwkcmuL6/6/) . Tweak the value at which it is fired according to your will.

Comment: Thanks, media query seems the ideal option to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

change first .row class to **.row-fluid** (to remove padding left and right)

remove css padding-left: 0 and padding-right: 0

Result
https://jsfiddle.net/qwkcmuL6/8/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-12 header">
```

**CSS**

```
.header {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.col-sm-6 > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.section-1 {
}

.section-2 {
}

.content {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

Comment: Good option if media query is not to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `@media query`.

```
@media screen and (min-width:768px){
  .section-1 {
    padding-left: 0px;
  }

  .section-2 {
    padding-right: 0px;
  }
}
```

Here is fiddle link: 
https://jsfiddle.net/qwkcmuL6/7/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```html
<div class="row">
    <!-- place two divs here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.